# jsonTest.jsp:43 Uncaught ReferenceError: requestJson is not defined

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

"Uncaught ReferenceError: function_name is not defined" always pops up when clicking on the button, but the function has been defined on the top. Can not figure out what is going wrong...

The jsp source is as following:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Json interaction Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function requestJson() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/requestJson.action",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: "{'name': 'Mobile', 'price': 999}",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" onclick="requestJson()" value="Click"/>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your jquery injection.

External script must be like this :

```
 <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
```